# Яндекс геокодер только внутри Казахстана

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Как сделать так чтобы искал ответы только внутри Казахстана? Если добавлять префикс Казахстан то он находит ответы которых быть не должны. Если использовать bbox как я вижу он возьмет квадрат. Карта Казахстана не квадратная, поэтому может взять лишнее. Фильтровать ответы не получится по той причине что мы используем pagination, и может сказаться на результатах неправильно

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема при добавлении префикса "Казахстан, "? Какие лишние объекты при этом находятся? В настоящее время другого метода ограничить территорию страной, городом, областью в геокодере нет, поскольку его задача - не поиск возможных адресов, а именно трансляция корректного адреса в координаты.

Comment: @YaCor' есть улица Казахстан например

Comment: То есть адрес вида "Казахстан, Казахстан, 5"? А город указать точно не забываете? Запрос "Казахстан, Усть-Каменогорск, улица Казахстан, 83" геокодер отлично обрабатывает, выдавая форматированный ответ: "formatted": "Казахстан, Восточно-Казахстанская область, Усть-Каменогорск, улица Казахстан, 83". Полноценно форматированный формат запроса, включая разделительные запятые в значительной степени определяет точность ответа сервиса.

Comment: Тут у нас сервис наподобие автокомплита, человек вводит адрес и должны выводится предложения ему

Comment: @YaCor' дело в том что по всему Казахстану все предложения из всех городов Казахстана должно быть

Comment: В таком случае вы используете не тот сервис. Геокодер преобразует координаты в адрес и наоборот. Он не создан для "угадаек" по недописанным адресам. Вам следует использовать саджест (можно и со своим провайдером поиска) https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/suggest или поиск JS API (можно также по своим объектам) https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_search. А уже выбранный пользователем результат можно геокодировать.

Comment: @YaCor' это же js api, а есть rest api?

Comment: http api для саджеста пока нет

Answer (score 0):

Я реализовал это так:

```js
    var locality = 'Чеченская Республика';
    var state = 'Грозный';

    var suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('address', {
    provider: {
    suggest: (function(request, options) {
              return ymaps.suggest(locality+", "+state+", "+request)
              })
    }});
```

И весь поиск у меня выполняется по Грозному.